# Copy file from assets to scared only if not empty

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code:

```
// Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = null;
    try {
        myInput = this.getAssets().open("Student info.txt");


    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Student info.txt";

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to copy a file from the assets folder to my sdcard. Now what I need is, if the file in the sdcard is empty, then go ahead and copy from assets to sdcard. Else, if the file in the sdcard is not empty, do not copy anything. How can I accomplish that? thank you

Comment: Check file size?

Comment: `Now what I need is, if the file in the sdcard is empty, then go ahead`. No. Normally one would copy if the file does not exist yet. But you can indeed add a check for file size 0 if the file already exists. And get getExternalStorageDirectory is NOT the micro SD card.

Comment: `// Path to the just created empty db`. ??? Why would you just have created an empty file? Makes no sense. And where did you do so? I do not see code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your above code if  file exists and is not empty

```
 String outFileName =
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Student info.txt"`;
File f = new File(outFileName);

           if (f.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File does not Exists or empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exists and is not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

OR

```
File f = new File(outFileName);

        if(f.exists()){
            //File exist
            if (f.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File is not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```